# Area of a digital disk

Tags: asymptotics, diophantine-equations

Considering the number of integer solutions of $x^2+y^2\le n^2$, a digital disk, which is obviously asymptotic to $\pi n^2$, how can we find a tight upper bound of the form

$$an^2+bn+c\ ?$$

The coefficients can be real, some may be zero if that helps. This is a form of  the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).

---

**Update:**

From Jack's answer, we have the upper bound

$$\pi\left(n+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *exactly* the Gauss circle problem, and by Voronoi's bounds we have
$$\left|\left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2: x^2+y^2\leq n^2 \right\} \right| = \pi n^2+O(n^{2/3}).$$
Two slightly different proofs can be found in Section 8 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: Except that this question prescribes the form of the bound, in such a badly chosen form, that makes it not have a 'tight' solution as required.

Comment: @logarithm: of course, $n^{2/3}\ll bn+c$ for any $b> 0$.

Comment: No, I need a true upper bound, not an asymptotic one. Obviously $(2n+1)^2$ works, but there must be tighter.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: then you can use Gauss' original one, that can be found in my notes, too. $a=\pi, b=\pi\sqrt{2}$ and $c=\frac{\pi}{2}$ work.

Comment: @logarithm: can you substantiate ?