# Calculate exactly and as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left[{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, sums-of-squares

I am counting the number of cases where $\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}$ is a perfect square as $k$ ranges from $1$ to $\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor$.  For the sum $N$ is fixed.  I don't know if a closed for expression is possible.  However in the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$ is very much needed to as many terms as possible.

This component arises from the calculation $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right\} =
\frac{1}{2}\, \left\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left[{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right] - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1,\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \not\in \mathbb{Z}}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} arctan \left({\cot \left({\pi \sqrt{{N}^{2} + {k}^{2}}}\right)}\right)$$  where $\left[{...}\right]$ are Iverson brackets.  Details of this question is posted as [Find the asymptotic expansion as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left\{{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}}\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516380/find-the-asymptotic-expansion-as-n-rightarrow-infty-of-sum-k-1-left-lf).  This part of a more general problem of counting the number of factorable quadratics of naive height $N$.  Note that I recently corrected this expression.

So far numerical tests indicate that as $N \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left[{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right] \sim 1 + \cdots$.

This looks like it may be connected with Gauss Circle Problem.

These are the current accumulative results of $\sum_{N = 1}^{{N}_{max}}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left[{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right]$

$$\begin{array}{ccc} {N}_{max} & \text{Accumulative Count} & \text{Average for } {N}_{max} & \text{Accumulative Count}/({N}_{max} \log \left({{N}_{max}}\right))\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ {10}^{2} & 22 & 0.22 & 0.0477724 \\ {10}^{3} & 436 & 0.436 & 0.0631175 \\ {10}^{4} & 6610 & 0.6610 & 0.0717672 \\ {10}^{5} & 88568 & 0.88568 & 0.0769292 \\ 2 \times {10}^{5} & 190668 & 0.95334 & 0.0781037 \\ 3 \times {10}^{5} & 297834 & 0.99278 & 0.07872 \\ 4 \times {10}^{5} & 408346 & 1.02087 & 0.0791416 \\ 5 \times {10}^{5} & 521315 & 1.04263 & 0.0794544 \end{array}$$  The case for $N = {10}^{5}$ reads that there were 88568 accumulative perfect squares between $N = 1$ and $N = {10}^{5}$ for an average of 0.88568 per $N$.  Counting additional data that is not shown in this table the new estimate as $N \rightarrow \infty$ based on curve fitting is $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \left[{\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}} \in \mathbb{Z}}\right] \sim 0.08\times \log \left({N}\right) + \cdots$.

The goal is to show this derivation!

Answer (score 2):

This is a hyperbolic version of the [Gauss circle problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228611/area-of-a-digital-disk/3228627#3228627) (see also Chapter 8 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)). 
By mimicking Gauss' approach it is pretty simple to prove that

$$ \sum_{k\leq N/2}\lfloor \sqrt{N^2+k^2}\rfloor = \int_{0}^{N/2}\sqrt{N^2+x^2}\,dx + O\left(\int_{0}^{N/2}\sqrt{\frac{N^2+2x^2}{N^2+x^2}}\,dx\right) $$
i.e. that
$$ \sum_{k\leq N/2}\lfloor \sqrt{N^2+k^2}\rfloor = \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)N^2+O(N).  $$
Improving the error term beyond $O(N)$ is tricky but doable due to the smoothness of $\sqrt{N^2+x^2}$.
By mimicking Voronoi's approach we get
$$ \sum_{k\leq N/2}\lfloor \sqrt{N^2+k^2}\rfloor = \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)N^2+O\left(N^{2/3}\right).  $$
This almost is the best we can get.
 Like in the Gauss circle problem, it can be shown that the error term is $\gg N^{1/2}$ in infinite cases.

Comment: This helps and your notes are very good.  This question is part of several related calculations of the floor, fractional part, etc. sums of $\sqrt{{N}^{2}+{k}^{2}}$ and its components.  The main question of the sum of the number of perfect squares is still open.  It looks like summing one leg of the Gauss circle problem and this sum is over part of the maximum range which would be $N$.